# Can we solve a hash table collision, by using a hash table again instead of a linked list?

Tags: c++, hash, hash-collision

Instead of using a linked list to avoid collision in hash table, can we use a hash table to avoid collision to obtain result in O(1) time instead of linear time complexity due to linked list?

Comment: Do you have a second hash function available for whatever data type you want to store in it?

Comment: Yes you can do it and it's a well known technique called `double hasing` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing.

Comment: @rakib_ interesting link, but a load factor of less than `.319` will need a much larger table.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Those numbers are an indicator. Based on the requirements the implementation has to be adapted. He can take the concept from there. To me, when you are using `hashing`, design the has function well, as if there's no collision in the first place. Handling the collision is second line of defense in hasing.

Comment: Double hashing could be helping to reduce the penalties of a bad hash function. However, it comes at a high cost of memory. Yet, you ain't able to prevent linked list as you could have a really bad hash function. (take the hash of the first element of a pair) so multiple elements would still collide after hashing twice.